# Perp dot product and intersection point between 2 vectors

Tags: math, vector

I have been reading a blog about the intersection of vectors. In this blog I have found something like this:

```
v3={vx:v2.p0.x-v1.p0.x, vy:v2.p0.y-v1.p0.y};
var t=perP(v3, v2)/perP(v1, v2);
ip={};
ip.x=v1.p0.x+v1.vx*t;
ip.y=v1.p0.y+v1.vy*t;

function perP(va, vb)
{
    pp = va.vx*vb.vy - va.vy*vb.vx;
    return pp;
}
```

This is how they calculate intersection of vector v2 vs v1. The part that I do not understand is the t calculation (that is the fraction on v2 that are the intersection point).

Could anyone explain why the division between the perp products is t? Have been reading some other info, etc... but can't figure it out.

P.D: The full blog post is: http://www.tonypa.pri.ee/vectors/tut05.html

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Product of v1 and v2 is equal to area of parallelogramm that formed by these vectors. The same is true for the product of v2 and v3. Two parallelograms have common base (v2), but different heights. Height1 = v1.DeltaY and height2 = v3.DeltaY = v1.DeltaY * t. So area ratio (and product ratio) is t

Comment: thanks for the answer MBo, but, the tutorial I pointed above talk about the dot products of v1 normal and v2, and v3 normal and v2 that is what he calls Perp dot product. Perhaps I did not fully followed you but still don't get the relationship between your answer and the way this guy calculates t.

Comment: perp dot product is one component of cross product , or cross product for 2D-case. Look at 'Matrix notation' and 'Geometric meaning' parts here:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product